# security in sql server 2000

Tags: sql-server-2000, windows-installer

How to create user and connect user in sql server 2000?

Comment: As part of an install or package?

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server 2000 if you are connected as a user with ALTER ANY LOGIN rights you can run this to create a login as set a default DB.

```
EXEC sp_addlogin 'MyName', 'MyPwd', 'MyDB';
GO
```

In 2005, connected as an admin or a user with ALTER ANY USER rights you can execute this to create a user

```
CREATE LOGIN MyName
    WITH PASSWORD = 'MyPwd';
USE MyDBName;
CREATE USER MyName FOR LOGIN MyName;
GO
```

If you are trying to include SQL Server Express / MSDE in an installation set you need to look at Unattended Installation.  Look at [Creating a Setup File Manually](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa176598(SQL.80).aspx) on MSDN.